# C# Console App erros - does not recognize/correctly evaluate int returned

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement, int

I am attempting to understand how methods work, and I thought that I had it down but it seems that I do not as my **RunSelect();** method is not doing what I hoped. On line #19, I ask the user to select value (1 or 2) and return that as an int (Run). Then on line #25 we do an if/if else/else statement depending on the int selected. regardless of what is selected, the int is not recognized and asks the user to try again - no matter what i enter, it is not recognized so my console methods fail and I am not sure what it is I am doing wrong.

I've tried tracing through my code, printing it out to analyze it, took the night to sleep on it. etc. I'm lost as to why it's not working. I'm newb, any help greatly appreciated. I don't think the problem is with my loops or methods, i think it's in how i'm handing off the int to the if statement. But i'm lost as to why it's not working as i thought it would.

thanks and cheers to all for any help

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace a032_Factorial_Fibonacci_Sequencer
{
class Program
{
    String command = "";

    //Need to get the runSelect to work as method

    public void Play()
    {
        Announcer("+ + + Welcome To MegaCorps Factorial Fibioci Sequencer + + +\n\n");

        int run = 0;

        do
        {
            RunSelect(run);

            if (run == 1) { RunFact(); }
            else if (run == 2) { RunFib(); }
            else
            {
                Announcer("Non Valid Selection"); 
                RunSelect(run);
            }

            Announcer("Enter 'Y' to Run another sequence? ");

            command = Console.ReadLine().ToLower().Trim();
        }
        while (command == "y" || command == "yes");
    }



    //HelperMethods

    public String Announcer(String strTxt)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(strTxt);
        return strTxt;
    }

    public int RunSelect(int run)
    {
        Announcer("Enter '1' to run Factor | Enter '2' to run Fibioci");
        run = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        return run;
    }

    public void Closer()
    { Console.Read(); }

    public void RunFact()
    {
        //craft program to factor a number entered and return factor
        //use double not int to handle factored numbers larger then 57+
        Console.WriteLine("Factorial Sequencer Entered/n/n");

        Announcer("Enter A Number to FACTOR: ");
        double num = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        double numNew = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
        { numNew = numNew * i; }

        Announcer("\nFACTORED result: " + numNew);
    }


    public void RunFib()
    {
        //craft program to fib a number entered and return fib
        //use double not int to handle factored numbers larger then 57+
        Console.WriteLine("Fibioci Sequencer Entered\n");

        Announcer("Enter A Number to FIBIOC: ");
        double iSequence = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Announcer("\nFIBIOC result: ");

        double iPrevious = -1;
        double iNext = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i <= iSequence; i++)
        {
            double iSum = iNext + iPrevious;
            iPrevious = iNext;
            iNext = iSum;

            Console.Write(iNext + ", ");
        }
    }





    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program myProgram = new Program();
        myProgram.Play();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem :** you are not storing the return value of the `RunSelect()` method.

**Solution :** You need to store the return value of the `RunSelect()` Method.otherwise variable `run` value will not be modified (still zero even after calling `RunSelect()` method).

Replace This:

```
RunSelect(run);
```

WIth This:

```
run=RunSelect(run);
```

**EDIT:** if you are calling a method which returns something then you need to read/store the `return` value of that method as it contains modified value.

**Step 1:** in your code you have initialised variable `run` using following statement:

```
int run = 0;
```

**Step 2:** inside `do-while` loop you have called `RunSelect()` method as below:

```
    do
    {
        RunSelect(run);
         ------
```

**Step 3:** in the method `RunSelect()` you are assigning the `run` variable with actual userinput given from `console` using following statements:

**Note:**   here run variable in `RunSelect()` method is local variable to that method so even if you assign value to `run` it wont be reflected to `run` variable declared in `Play()` function.

```
public int RunSelect(int run)
    {
        Announcer("Enter '1' to run Factor | Enter '2' to run Fibioci");
        run = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());/here you are assigning userinput to run variable.
        return run;
    }
```

**Step 4:** you are sending back the modified variable value `run` to the caller of this method(`RunSelect()`):

**Step 5:** there you are not storing this `return` value sent by `RunSelect()` method again into `run` variable as below:

```
RunSelect(run);
```

so still `run` variable will have the initialised value `zero`.

to make it work you need to just store the return value of the `RunSelect()` method as  below:

```
run=RunSelect(run);
```

Comment: I'm amazed by the simplicity of this solution, which completely works. I don't understand exactly what it is doing thought/how it is doing what it is doing so I must research this - is there any place you can point me to to understand better what you are doing (assigning the int run to equal the method that gets the value)?

Comment: @Chezshire: you are welcome, let me edit my postto add some more information.

Comment: Hello Sudhakar - thanks of the help and I will go over this I promise, I came down with the flu and have been ill the last few days (sorry for not responding sooner)

Answer (score 1):

You have a Function which accepts a value parameter and returns an int, but you aren't assigning the return int to anything.  In your case, the parameter is redundant, since it isn't used within the method anyway.  in C#, by default, parameters are value parameters. This means that a new storage location is created for the variable in the function member declaration, and it starts off with the value that you specify in the function member invocation. If you change that value, that doesn't alter any variables involved in the invocation.

try this instead:

```
public int RunSelect()
{
    Announcer("Enter '1' to run Factor | Enter '2' to run Fibioci");
    int run = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    return run;
}
```

and in your method call:

```
int run = RunSelect();
```

no need to pre-initialize run before the call, so you can remove the line `int run = 0;`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I attempted it but received a run time error that said 'Overload Method requires....'. Thank for the help, it makes me feel like I am learning and while I don't understand the breakdown at least i was able to ask my question in an intelligent fashion and understand what you are saying. And also just thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

When you call `RunSelect(run)`, you are not changing the current value of `run`. Passing in `run` cannot change its value. The `RunSelect` function returns a new value that you have to assign like this: `run = RunSelect(run)`.

Also you will notice that `RunSelect` does not use the value of `run` that is passed in, so it can just as easily be written like this:

```
    public int RunSelect()
    {
        Announcer("Enter '1' to run Factor | Enter '2' to run Fibioci");
        int run = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        return run;
    }
```

Comment: Oh - thanks this explains the above better - thank you very much.